# Ошибки при попытке подключить Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

При попытке подключить Spring Security по следующему коду https://github.com/proselytear/SpringSecurityApp проявилась 2 ошибки:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired 
dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.core.newbie.service.UserService com.core.newbie.controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao com.core.newbie.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
... 31 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could 
not autowire field: private com.core.newbie.service.UserService com.core.newbie.controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao com.core.newbie.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 47 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao com.core.newbie.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 49 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao com.core.newbie.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 60 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 62 common frames omitted
```

User.java (брал изначально из https://github.com/rainningToSnow/springMVC-mybatis-postgresql, потом внес некоторые правки, попытавшись добавить связь с ролями):

```
package com.core.newbie.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

public class User {

private Integer id;

private String userName;

private String password;

private Integer age;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(final String userName) {
    this.userName = userName == null ? null : userName.trim();
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(final String password) {
    this.password = password == null ? null : password.trim();
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(final Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

UserDao.java:

```
package com.core.newbie.dao;

import com.core.newbie.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

RoleDao.java:

```
package com.core.newbie.dao;

import com.core.newbie.model.Role;
import com.core.newbie.model.User;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RoleDao extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
}
```

UserService.java:

```
package com.core.newbie.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.core.newbie.model.User;

public interface UserService {
User getUserById(int userId);

User findByUsername(String username);

void save(User user);

List<User> getAll();
}
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
package com.core.newbie.impl;

import com.core.newbie.dao.RoleDao;
import com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao;
import com.core.newbie.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.core.newbie.model.Role;
import com.core.newbie.model.User;
import com.core.newbie.service.UserService;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Autowired
private UserMapper userMapper;

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
public User getUserById(final int userId) {
    return userMapper.selectByPrimaryKey(userId);
}

@Override
public void save(final User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(roleDao.getOne(1L));
    user.setRoles(roles);
    userDao.save(user);
}

@Override
@Select("select * from n_user")
public List<User> getAll() {
    return userMapper.findAll();
}

@Override
public User findByUsername(String username) {
    return userDao.findByUsername(username);
}
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:

```
package com.core.newbie.service;

import com.core.newbie.dao.UserDao;
import com.core.newbie.model.Role;
import com.core.newbie.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }
    return new 
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), 
user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
}
```

UserActionTest.java:

```
package com.core.newbie.action;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.core.newbie.model.User;
import com.core.newbie.service.UserService;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-mybatis.xml"})
public class UserActionTest {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserActionTest.class);
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void setUserService(final UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

public UserService getUserService() {
    return userService;
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    final User user = userService.getUserById(1);
    logger.info(JSON.toJSON(user));
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    final User user = new User();
    user.setId(112);
    user.setAge(14);
    user.setPassword("12");
    user.setUserName("derrick-2");
    userService.insetUser(user);
    logger.info(JSON.toJSON(user));
}
}
```

Соединение к базе данных корректное. Помогите разобраться.

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Также добавил конфиг spring-security.xml. Его нужно где-то подключать, чтобы авторизация работала?

Comment: Ощущение что вы кодите в notepad'e или у Вас не работает инспекция кода в клипсе. Покажите код сущности User

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Это Eclipse for EE.

Comment: Немного поправил структуру и обновил вопрос. Осталось 2 ошибки.

Comment: Всё просто. В классе `User` нет метода `getUsername()`, который Вы пытаетесь вызывать в указанной сообщением об ошибке строке кода. Есть `getUserName()`. Подозреваю, что в классе (точнее интерфейсе) UserDao аналогично нет метода `insetUser(...)`. Вероятно просто `inset(...)`, не знаю, spring-ом давно не увлекаюсь. Можите составить ответ и оставить себе свои 50 очков:) И впредь быть внимательнее.

Comment: Ох, и правда. Завтра с утра попробую все выправить и отпишусь. В любом случае спасибо!

Comment: Обновил вопрос в соответствие с текущей ситуацией.

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке прямо указывает на проблемы с зависимостями. В каком бине, с каким полем. Надо проверить, что все бины, которые внедряются по `@Autowire`, имеют нужные аннотации (@Service или что там ещё бывает) или же прописаны в spring.xml. Что не возникает ошибок в конструкторах и методах инициализации бинов. Последняя ошибка говори, что не может найти бин `userDao`. Из-за этого целая цепь ошибок выше.

Comment: "Последняя ошибка говори, что не может найти бин userDaoПоследняя ошибка говори, что не может найти бин userDao" - да, тоже заметил, но не понимаю, как выправить. С Java работаю недавно.

Comment: Надо перечитать раздел руководства spring про доступ к базам данных. Репозитарии там всякие... Как они определяются в программе, как инжектятся. Если реализация должна была сгенерится на лету, то может какая-то часть spring-а не активирована или ей чего-то не хватает.

Comment: Попробуйте аннотацию `@Repository` на `Dao` классы добавить